# Finding sheet music

Tags: sheet-music, keyboard, digital-piano

What do you call a Sheet where there is no Vocal? I play the piano, where the right hand plays the melody(vocal?) and my left hand will play the background. I have problems on finding music sheet because when i do search they have the melody. I only want the background piano sheet while my partner will sing the song. Is there a word that i can use for easy access for the sheet i am looking?

sorry for my bad english. I dont even know if I am asking the right question.  THANK YOU.

Comment: Whether or not there is a vocal part has nothing to do with whether it’s called sheet music. Sheet music just means music that is written down, but it implies that it’s written with staves and note shapes, not with only chord names or tablature.

Answer (score 1):

Most good sheet music for piano and vox will have three lines of music together. Top is vox, other two are both piano. Ignore the top line and play the others while someone sings.

Answer (score 1):

You might try searching for "**accompaniment**" version (as you are "accompanying" the vocalist).